# Find Homography matrix from Fundamental matrix

Tags: opencv, geometry, computer-vision, homography

I'm trying to compute Homography matrix `H` given a set of correspondences and the Fundamental matrix `F`.

From the principle of Epipolar geometry I know this can be done by cross product of epiline and `F` from [Epipole Geometry](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~marc/tutorial/node44.html)

`[e_ij] x F_ij  = H_ij`

[image: Epipolar image]

I'm using `OpenCV` for finding Fundamental matrix `F` from set of matches between two views using `cv::findFundamentalMat()`.

My question is that how can I find `e_ij` and how to use it in order to compute `H`. In `OpenCV` there is a function `cv::computeCorrespondEpilines()` that finds epilines corespond to each given point.

It's worth mentioning that I'm not interested in computing `H` directly from set of matches but only from computed Fundamental matrix.

Thanks

Comment: Actually this is a mathematical question ;)

Comment: In theory, the fundamental matrix should be of rank 2 and it's kernel (both right and left) is just the epipole. So if your formula for `H` is correct the problem boils down to finding the kernel of `F`.
Of course, since the matrix is probably computed from some real-world measurements, the rank will always be 3, so you should to use something like the **SVD** decomposition to find the eigenvector corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue (closest to zero), and you're good to go.

Comment: Your epiline notation is confusing, because `e` usually denotes the epipole. You should use `l` for an epiline.

Comment: @AldurDisciple I'm not sure about `e` neither. that's why I provided a link to the reference I used. If that is epipole, how should I compute and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, notice that the equation (C29) you mentioned from your link uses a line l with same coordinates as e<sub>ij</sub>, which is the epipole in image j. Therefore, l=e<sub>ij</sub> is not an epiline, since dot( e<sub>ij</sub> , e<sub>ij</sub> ) == norm(e<sub>ij</sub>)² == 1 != 0.

If I stick to the notations given in your link, you can compute the epipole e<sub>ij</sub> as the left null-vector of F<sub>ij</sub>. You can obtain it by calling `cv::SVD::solveZ` on the transpose of `F_ij`. Then, as is mentioned in your link, the homography H<sub>ij</sub> (which maps points from image i to image j) can be computed as H<sub>ij</sub> = [e<sub>ij</sub>]<sub>x</sub> F<sub>ij</sub>, where the notation [e<sub>ij</sub>]<sub>x</sub> refers to the 3x3 skew-symmetric operator. A definition of this notation can be found in the [Wikipedia article on cross-product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication).

However, be aware that such an homography H<sub>ij</sub> defines a mapping from image i to image j via the plane backprojected from image j using the line with same coordinates as e<sub>ij</sub>. In general, this will give a result which is very different from the result returned by `cv::findHomography`, where the resulting homography is a mapping from image i to image j via the dominant plane in the observed scene. Hence, you will be able to approximately register the two images using the homography returned by `cv::findHomography`, but in general this will not be the case for the homography obtained using the method above.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The notation is now clear for me. The question is that is this method sensible for finding `H`? The reason for using `F` rather than directly computing `H` is that I want to relax non-planarity to some extent. I know it is possible to retrieve `H` from `F` but I could not find an implementation so far.

Comment: @HamidBazargani unfortunately you cannot relax non-planarity for homographies when mapping from one image to another (unless they are acquired from the same optical center). You can derive the homography for any plane you like, but there is always one, even if its not easy to see which one. If you want to register two images more accurately, you should have a look at optical-flow and/or dense stereo matching techniques.